# jQuery show/hide for one item only on a page

Tags: jquery, hide, show

My problem is that I have some table data that gets loaded into the page from a MySQL database with a PHP while loops, it lists a teams results. In that loop there is a table row that gets hidden by default with a class of "scorers", there is then a show/hide button to say weather to show or hide that row.

But that "scorers" class is on the page multiple times as there are multiple results, so if you hit the show/hide button it opens all the cells with the class of "scorers".

Example code is here: http://codepen.io/anthwinter/pen/vLJiy

I need to be able to only show/hide the current scorers for that result only. What would be my best way of doing so?

Thanks in advance

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>One</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="showHide">show/hide</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="scorers">Show or hide this content one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>Two</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="showHide">show/hide</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="scorers">Show or hide this content two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQ:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scorers").hide();

    $(".showHide").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".scorers").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By just doing `$('.scorers').toggle("fast");` will target all your `.scorers` TD elements,
you need to point the the *clicked one* by using `this` and than do some DOM traversal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scorers").hide();

    $(".showHide").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.scorers').toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/next/
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Thanks, I found this worked without the ".find('.scorers')". With it, it didn't seem to work. But yeah, all ok now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).closest('TR').next().find('.scorers').toggle("fast");
```